# Node label's letter case in graph incorrectly displayed

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Upon constructing the following graph, I *expected* the node labels to appear as per what is provided. The letter case of **Node E** is not in CAPS as shown below. Please correct me if I misunderstood something here.

[image: i1]

Comment: [`E`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/E.html) is the exponential constant in Mathematica.

Comment: @kglr Rookie mistake. Please convert your comment to answer. I shall mark this solved.

Comment: abhilash, done.

Answer (score 1):

[E](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/E.html?q=E) is a reserved symbol is Mathematica:

[image]

[image]

Btw, so are `C` and `D`.